# equivalent to cut -f1-3,5 in awk

Tags: awk

I want fields 1,2,3,5

With cut I do:

```
cut -f1-3,5
```

However with awk I would do:

```
awk '{for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {if (i!=4) {print $i}} }'
```

But I want to make it more succinct. Moreover, in other cases I could have more fields with varying distances. `awk '{for (i in 1 2 3 5) {print $i}}'` doesn't work. How can I do this

Comment: You sure you want to start with `i=0` instead of `i=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what `cut` does and a bit more:

```
$ echo 'a b c d e f g' |
awk -v ranges='1-3,5' '
    BEGIN {
        split(ranges,r,/,/)
        for ( i=1; i in r; i++ ) {
            n = split(r[i],range,/-/)
            for ( j=range[1]; j<=range[n]; j++ ) {
                f[++onf] = j
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=onf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<onf ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
a b c e
```

The above assumes if you specify the same field number multiple times then you want it printed that many times, and you want the fields printed in the order you specify so you can, for example, rearrange order and/or duplicate fields, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'a b c d e f g' |
awk -v ranges='6,1-3,5,2,1' '
    BEGIN {
        split(ranges,r,/,/)
        for ( i=1; i in r; i++ ) {
            n = split(r[i],range,/-/)
            for ( j=range[1]; j<=range[n]; j++ ) {
                f[++onf] = j
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=onf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<onf ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
f a b c e b a
```

Answer (score 3):

For the job of picking fields by position number and field ranges etc `cut` does the job better. If you really want to mimic this behavior in `awk` assuming you have other tasks to do in awk as well, you may consider following code:

```bash
cat fcut.awk

BEGIN {
   n = split(f, a, /,/)
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
      if (split(a[i], b, /-/) == 2) {
         for (j=b[1]; j<=b[2]; ++j)
            fld[j]
      }
      else
         fld[a[i]]
   }
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if (i in fld)
         s = (st++ ? s OFS : "") $i
   }
   print s
   s = st = ""
}
```

Now run it as:

```bash
awk -v f='1-3,5' -f fcut.awk file
```

Comment: Thank you. At the end, I end up doing `... | cut -f1,3.5 | awk ...<for i=0; i++...>`

Comment: `(s == "" ? "" : s OFS)` would fail if a different FS was used and a field was empty.